# Data isnt loaded on page refresh, only on transitions

Tags: meteor

I currently have a problem with data not being ready upon full page refreshes. I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'earnings' of undefined
```

However, the data gets loaded correctly when I transition to the route through a pathFor link from another template.

I have the following route defined:

```
  this.route('overview', {
    path: '/overview',
    layoutTemplate: 'dashboardLayout',
    loginRequired: 'entrySignIn',
    waitOn: function() {
      Meteor.subscribe('overviewData');
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        earnings: Meteor.user().earnings,
      };
    },
    onAfterAction: function() {
      SEO.set({
        title: 'Overview | ' + SEO.settings.title
      });
    }
  });
```

Which subscribes to this publication:

```
Meteor.publish('overviewData', function() {
  if (!this.userId) { return null; }
  return [
    Meteor.users.find(this.userId, { fields: { earnings: 1} }),
    Tabs.find({ userId: this.userId })
  ];
});
```

Piece of template referencing data:

```
<div class="period pull-left">
        Period <span class='amount'>{{earnings.period}}</span>$
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.ready()` before sending data, and also add return in `waitOn` function

try the following code

```
this.route('overview', {
    path: '/overview',
    layoutTemplate: 'dashboardLayout',
    loginRequired: 'entrySignIn',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('overviewData');
    },
    data: function() {
     if(this.ready()){
      return {
        earnings: Meteor.user().earnings,
      }
     }
    },
    onAfterAction: function() {
      SEO.set({
        title: 'Overview | ' + SEO.settings.title
      });
    }
  });
```

**EDIT**

This works because `this.ready()` will be true only after the subscriptions which are returned by `waitOn()` function completed.

In your code your sending the data without checking whther the data is subscribed or not(or the data is sent to client or not). So it return `undefined`

Comment: worked great, thanks, i am not sure why though, since I have other subscriptions defined the way, where that error didnt show

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be caused by the fact that it takes a moment for the browser to read the cookie data to log back in. Maybe try adding an onBeforeAction for your route that checks if the user is logging in before rerouting.

```
this.route('overview', {
  path: '/overview',
  layoutTemplate: 'dashboardLayout',
  loginRequired: 'entrySignIn',
  waitOn: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('overviewData');
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      earnings: Meteor.user().earnings,
    };
  },
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
      if (Meteor.loggingIn())
        this.render('loadingTemplate');
    }
    else {
      this.next();
    }
  },
  onAfterAction: function() {
    SEO.set({
      title: 'Overview | ' + SEO.settings.title
    });
  }
});
```

Meteor users are a reactive data source, so the route should run again when `loggingIn()` is finished and shouldn't throw an undefined error.

Comment: Didnt make a different. I also have other routes where it works fine